# Casting string to userdefined class type

Tags: java, string

I have created class A.
I want String "hi" to be assigned to type A.is it possible.if yes,how.please help.
How we can cast string user defined class type.

Comment: Have your tried to do that?

Comment: Simply put, you can't

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? Do you want your string to represent some value in your class?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You can't *cast* `String` to anything except `String` or `Object`. Do you mean 'convert'?

Comment: Why? Buy a good book. Read it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to assign a `String` to your class `A`, unless your class `A` is the `String` class. If you are trying to store a `String` in your class, then you need an instance field and a setter for that instance field.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, you will get `inconvertible types` error if you are trying to do `A yourObject = (A) new String("A")`.

- You can perform a downcasting operation only if the two types come in same hierarchy.
- `String` does not come in the hierarchy of `A` so  it gives error `inconvertible types`

Comment: @DaftPunk, I'm sorry but I don't see whether I have mentioned extending String or something similar